# How do I get a Lucario?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I have a level 59 Riolu in my party and I have it at max happiness. However, because the games are set 12 hours apart, I am not sure if I level it up at night or during the day IRL. I'm also not sure if I need to max out it's happiness during the day as well.

Answer (score 2):

Two conditions need to be met to evolve Riolu: its happiness must be at least 220, and it must level up during the day.

The "day" counts as ingame time, so if you're playing Moon, you want to level up Riolu during real night. It doesn't matter when Riolu reached the necessary level of happiness, it just needs to level up during the day.

Comment: Worth mentioning that day/night change at 6AM and 6PM (according to your 3DS's clock). So, [plan to level up time-based evolutions accordingly](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Time#Generation_VII)